# Conjugacy Class of Dihedral Group of Order 12

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the dihedral group of order 12: 
$D_{12}=<a,b:a^6=b^2=3, ba=a^5b>$, where $a$ is a rotation of a hexagon by 60 degrees, and $b$ is a reflection across a diagonal of two vertices.

I am looking to find the conjugacy class $cl_{D_{12}}(b)$. I have, $cl_{D_{12}}(b)$ = $\{b, aba^{-1}, a^2ba^{-2}, a^3ba^{-3}\}$.

Have I found this conjugacy class correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean $a^6 = b^2 = 1$, not $3$.

Answer (score 1):

By hand, we have $b,aba^{-1},a^2ba-{2},a^3ba^{-3},a^4ba{-4},a^5ba^{-5},bab(ba)^{-1},ba^2b(ba^2)^{-1},ba^3b(ba^3)^{-1},ba^4b(ba^4)^{-1},ba^5b(ba^5)^{-1}$.

But these simplify to $\{b,ba^4,ba^2\}$, using the relations.

Comment: I really like your work!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^3 = a^{-3}$, so that 
$$a^3ba^{-3} = a^3ba^3 = a^3a^{15}b = a^{18}b = b.$$

It might be easier if you think of the elements of $D_{12}$ as
$$1, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, b, ba, ba^2, ba^3, ba^4, ba^5,$$
and remember that always $a^kb = ba^{6-k}$.

As a hint, $D_{12}$ has two conjugacy classes of size $1$, two of size $2$, and $2$ of size $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the class equation: $$1+1+2+2+3+3.$$

The center is $\{e,a^3\}.$   Those correspond to the ones.   There's four rotations left.    We must have $$\underbrace{1+1}_{\text Z(D_{12})}+\underbrace {2}_{\text \{a,a^5\}}+\underbrace 2_{\text \{a^2,a^4\}}+\underbrace 3_{\text \{r,ra^2,ra^4\}}+\underbrace 3_{\text \{ra,ra^3,ra^5\}}$$